# Grabbing lines from text but fail to get multiple returns

Tags: python, regex

### tl;dr

https://repl.it/repls/AbandonedSoulfulNetbsd (All the code).

### Regex:

https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/1/

**EDIT:** The regex when executed shows only: 1 match, n steps. Instead of number of matches to correspond to the number of line number actually found in the entire text.

### main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # See text content in the textfile.txt, 
    # https://repl.it/repls/AbandonedSoulfulNetbsd
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[0-9].*', re.M | re.S)
    for m in re.finditer(pattern, text): 
        print(m.group(0))
```

### **Desire results**

Well, I want to grab all the lines that actually begin with a digit (regardless what the digit is), however, I don't know if there's a regex way of getting each line separately? Or, should something like `re.split()` be used instead?

### **UPDATE:**

This, `^[0-9](.*?)$` regex pattern gives me 13 matches, 
https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/2/ - however, I am still not able to make it work in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the `s` flag and may use `\d` instead:

```
^\d.*$
```

The singleline flag changes the behaviour of the dot insofar as it now matches newlines as well, hence - with your quantifier - everything. `\d` includes `[0-9]` (and some other digits as well). See [**your modified demo**](https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/3).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to work in Python, I get the results on one line at matching object [0]. That's not what I want.

Comment: My fault, this does work! But one must only enable re.M and exclude the other flags. Awesome! Here's a modified version: https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/4

Comment: Jan, how can this be extended to ignore n. that is e.g. "11. " so ignore all line numbers that aren't followed by something else. [^\s*] doesn't seem to fully work.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Several ways, one being to require at least one character after the digits with `^\d.+$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Puggjm/8 If this does not help, post another question.